# Loose coupling of COM in C# or How to avoid COMException 0x80040154

Tags: c#, com, vb6, sharpdevelop

I have a .Net 2 C# application I am developing which uses a VB 6 generated COM DLL. The VB DLL is updated frequently any my application crashes with a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154).  The part of the COM DLL I use does not change but the version (and CLSID) will.

The "Specific Version" option for the reference is false. The WrapperTool is tlbimp.

How do I tell my application not to worry about changes in the DLL? Is there any way of checking just the functions I am using?

Comment: I have used this code elsewhere:

// returns reference for the topmost window.

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]

public static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

Is this the only answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of the most common COM errors, "Class not registered".  It starts at VB6, it has an option to control binary compatibility.  I forgot exactly what that looks like, it's been too long.  If you don't control this, VB6 is going to create a new COM server with different CLSID values.  That requires re-registering the DLL with Regsvr32.exe.  And re-generating the interop library with Tlbimp.exe.  The latter step is probably the one you missed.

Note that using different CLSID values is a hard requirement for COM, it *must* be done when the public interface changes.  But not when only the implementation changes.

Comment: Thanks.  The newer COM DLL has been registered. I have also found out that the CLSID has not changed.

Comment: Sorry Mr Bugz.  I missed a step I always miss, the Tlbimp.exe step.  The IDE (SharpDevelop) must invoke it when compiling.

Comment: tlbimp.exe does not exist on the compiling machine. I wonder what magic SharpDevelop is using to generate the interop DLL...